# Passing class method within an arrow method callback is losing `this` context

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am struggling in understanding why this snippet would lose the context of `this` ?
What I wanted to achieve is to remove one (first) argument from the function that's been executed which has been achieved. The problem is that right now I cannot access anything from the class instance scope. Does anyone have idea on what has happened here? I believe it could be related to double arrow method that's been used but I have no idea on how to fix it.

```
class Callback {
    test = 'test';
    
    callback(a) {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(a);
    }
}


const callback = new Callback();

const serverAdapter = (cb) => (_, args, context) => cb(args, context?.req);

console.log("Having a context");
callback.callback('test');

console.log("Losing the context");
serverAdapter(callback.callback)(1,2,3);
```

outcome:

```
[LOG]: "Having a context" 
[LOG]: Callback: {
  "test": "test"
} 
[LOG]: "test" 
[LOG]: "Losing the context" 
[LOG]: undefined 
[LOG]: 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
serverAdapter(callback.callback)(1,2,3);
```

to this:

```
serverAdapter(callback.callback.bind(callback))(1,2,3);
```

When you pass `obj.foo` as an argument, only a reference to the method is passed as a plain function and then when the function you passed it to calls that function, it's just called as a plain function, not as `obj.foo()` so there is no longer any reference to the original object.

There are multiple ways to solve this.  Using `.bind()` is one such mechanism.

---

If you were really going to use this class as a callback manager, then you could build the binding into the callback class itself like this:

```
class Callback {
    test = 'test';

    constructor() {
        // create bound method
        this.callback = this.callbackOp.bind(this);
    }
    
    callbackOp(a) {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(a);
    }
}
```

Then, you could just pass `obj.callback` as a callback and it would automatically be bound to `obj` for you.